# Convert native MySQL query to JPA query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is the structure of my model:

```java
public class Student() 
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String studentID;
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "student_detail_id")
   private StudentDetail studentDetailID;
}
```

And StudentDetail:

```java
public class StudentDetail 
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String email;
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "studentDetailID")
   private Student student; 
}
```

I want to have a query that from `StudentDetail` checks:

1. if (Student doesn't exists): return "Student doesn't exist"
2. if (Student exists but doesn't have studentDetail): return "Student doesn't have detail"

I was able to write a native query that works, but now I want to convert it to JPA query and unable to.

```java
public interface StudentDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDetail, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = "select if(count(s.id) > 0, 'true', 'false') 
                 from student_detail sd JOIN student s
                 WHERE s.studentID = :studentID")
    boolean existsByStudentStudentID(@Param("studentID") String studentID);}
```

I have tried derived query:

`boolean existsByStudentStudentID(@Param("studentID") String studentID);`

And JPA query:

```java
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(s.id) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END
        FROM StudentDetail sd LEFT JOIN sd.student s
        WHERE s.studentID = :studentID")
```

Both of them return with `1` mentioned above no matter if it's the case of `1` or `2`.

Comment: Hello. My first advice is to use JPABuddy plugin for IJIDEA if u use it. And the possible answer - u need to use `@EntityGraph` annotation to join entities through JPA Query (plugin will help u with that action if u don't want to spend time)

Comment: I tried JPABuddy, feels like it's a tool for noob more than anything, it basically generate things I already know. The solution is instead of using inner join/join I need to use right join for some reason. Haven't tested it fully yet so maybe it's just a quick fix.